# Android Studio inline compiler is not showing red lamp errors

Tags: android-studio

My Android studio is not showing the red lamp when I have an error but gradle does it when I compile the project. The strangest thing is that only happens in .java files, for xml files is working. I have tried to clean project and rebuild, reinitialize Android Studio and I have checked that power save mode is unselected.

My gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    debug {
        java.srcDirs = ['src', 'build/generated-sources', 'src-debug']
    }

    release {
        java.srcDirs = ['src', 'build/generated-sources', 'src-release']
    }
    androidTest.setRoot('project-test')
    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['project-test/src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['project-test/src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['project-test/src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['project-test/src']
        res.srcDirs = ['project-test/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['project-test/assets']
    }
}
```

Also my source folder in project is marked as a "J" inside a red circle.

Does someone knows where is the problem?? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. The problem was that somehow in gradle file my src foulder was like a resource foulder:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
-->     resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
      ...
}
```

I changed this line like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
....
}
```

I hope this can be useful for other people!

Comment: I have two projects and both of them are giving me this same error. Can you please help?